# Factorial macros while loop

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am trying to write a open office macros code to compute factorial using while loop but I am finding it difficult. Heres my code so far. Any help is gladly appreciated.

```
Sub DisplayFact()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nFact As Long

    'Initialsing n to zero 
    if n = 0
        return nFact = 0 ;

    While n <= 4

        MsgBox "n = " & n & " ,  nFact =  " & nFact 

        n = n + 1
        nFact= n*nFact(n-1)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a previous version of the code? `Sub` is not a `Function` and  `return` is not valid in VBA

Comment: Is this "open office" as in the ***software*** OpenOffice?

Comment: Not sure if it's available in OppenOffice, but maybe you can use the [`Fact`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FACT-function-ca8588c2-15f2-41c0-8e8c-c11bd471a4f3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) Excel function

Comment: @Slai - Yeah, the only time I roll my own factorial (with `Decimal`) is if I need to avoid precision loss from a `Double`.

Comment: And the definition of zero factorial implied in the code (=0) is *wrong*. It should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DisplayFact()

    Dim n As Long

    n = 0 'Initialsing n to zero

    While n <= 4
        MsgBox "n = " & n & ", Fact = " & WorksheetFunction.Fact(n)
        n = n + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

or maybe:

```
Do
.
.
Loop While n <= 4
```

or

```
Do While n <= 4
.
.
.
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `For..To` loop for this kind of thing:

```
For n = 0 To 4
    MsgBox "n = " & n & " ,  nFact =  " & nFact 
    nFact= n * nFact(n - 1)
Next
```

This loop will start with `n` having a value of `0` and will automatically increment the value of `n` by 1 on each iteration.

You can also change the increment by using the optional `Step` parameter:

```
For n = 1 To 10 Step 2
    '// n will go through 1 > 3 > 5 > 7 > 9 and then exit
Next

For n = 10 To 1 Step - 3
    '// n will go through 10 > 7 > 4 > 1 and then exit
Next
```

Comment: @Comintern actually, looking again I don't think any of the OP code makes sense....

Comment: well seems OP started with a recursive version where `nFact` was a function and tried changing it to iterative

Comment: yeah, I think the whole thing is also supposed to be a function where `n` is passed as an argument.